# How do I rewrite specific URL's to not have .php

Tags: .htaccess

How can I rewrite a specific page's to not have the .php at the end. I only want to rewrite certain pages not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You find the last period that appears after the last "/" and, if found, remove the period and everything that follows. (If the URL ends with "/", then the URL is a path and not a filename.) Then append ".php".

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to clarify the conditions under which you want to rewrite `/my/path` to `/my/path.php` all this information would go into the rewrite condition. Then the subsequent rewrite rule would just be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

For instance, if you wanted to rewrite all paths that do not point to static files or directories to append `.php`, your .htaccess would look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

In practice, a pretty common methodology for rewriting is to route all requests for things other than static assets to a single handler that then delegates the request appropriately. For instance:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

The requested URI is still accessible in PHP via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: It would be URLHERE.com/PAGENAME.php

Comment: Can you show me how it would look if I was on website.com/home.php, I want to turn it into website.com/home on only that page.

Comment: If it's only that page, then the only thing you need is `RewriteRule ^home$ ^home.php$`

Answer (score 0):

This is for individual pages, this will change page1.php to page1:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /page1\.php\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule .+ http://www.yourwebsite.com/page1  [R=301,QSA]

RewriteRule ^page1/? /page1.php [QSA,L]
```

This one is for multiple pages, page1.php becomes page1, page2.php becomes page2 etc..:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(page1|page2|page3)\.php\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.yourwebsite.com/%1/ [R=301,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3)/? /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Executed on page1 it will give the result http://www.yourwebsite.com/page1/. If you want to remove the last /  just replace http://www.yourwebsite.com/%1/ with http://www.yourwebsite.com/%1

Edit @ Comment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /home\.php\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule .+ http://www.website.com/home  [R=301,QSA]

RewriteRule ^home/? /home.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can you show me how it would look if I was on website.com/home.php, I want to turn it into website.com/home on only that page.

Comment: Edited my answer, I believe this is what you need. I'm not entirely sure though as I'm no wizard at this :D